# Visualforce template and page action attribute: order of execution

Tags: visualforce, order-of-execution, page-template

Basically I have simple vf template MainTemplate and two pages (PageOne and PageTwo), which use this template. All pages & template share the same controller MainController. There are three action methods inside controller: beforePageOneIsRendered (bind to PageOne apex:page action attribute), beforePageTwoIsRendered (bind to PageTwo), and beforeMainTemplateIsRendered (bind to MainTemplate action).

And finally the question: is there any particular order in which action methods are called in case if both page & template has this action attribute specified ? I would expect to have beforeMainTemplateIsRendered action called first, and only after that appropriate page action - e.g. beforePageOneIsRendered for the first page. But my practical experiments show that it varies, and basically order could be arbitrary.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Sounds like you are experiencing why controller properties and methods should be written to work whatever order they are referenced in.